# Reliablity Crow Amsaa Model

Tags: python, reliability

I am using the `reliability_growth()` function from the [reliability docmentation](https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reliability%20growth.html) in Python. Specifically, I'm working with the following code:

```
reliability_data = reliability_growth(times=valid_times.to_list(), model="Crow-AMSAA")
```

The `valid_times` DataFrame contains my data. The `reliability_data` object gives me the cumulative MTBF at the final failure time, but I'm interested in obtaining all failure times for further analysis.

The library provides a plot of the failure times, but I need to create a custom chart. Is there a way to retrieve the individual failure times from the reliability_data object, so I can use them as X-axis and Y-axis values for my plot?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!